# Почему ответ true?

Tags: php

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/710e111f015bdbbd0067448533303c6926e7b10a

```
$a = in_array('test', [0] );
var_dump($a);
```

Что-то я не понял почему ответ true показывается?

Comment: Надо `$a = in_array('test', [0], true);`, чтоб ещё типы сравнивал.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Ответ

Используйте строгий режим у функции [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
$a = in_array('test', [0], true);
var_dump($a);
```

## Объяснение

Потому что в PHP слабая динамическая типизация. Когда вы ищете строку в массиве с числами, то интерпретатор делает приведение типов. В вашем случае строка `test` преобразуется к числу и будет равна `0`.

Если вы попробуйте найти строку `test` в массиве, где нет числа `0`, то будет `false`:

```
$a = in_array('test', [1] );
var_dump($a);
```

В PHP нужно всегда про это помнить и не использовать неявное преобразование, а использовать явное приведение типов и строгий режим сравнения.

```
var_dump('test' == 0);   // true
var_dump('test' === 0);  // false
var_dump('1test' == 1);  // true
var_dump('1test' === 1); // false
```

В документации есть полезная таблица сравнений разных типом между собой – http://php.net/manual/ru/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose